# Smooth Curve Definition

Tags: smooth-manifolds, curves

Just wanted to brush up on my definitions.

The question states:

Let $r :\mathbb{R}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a representation of a curve. Whats the definition for $r$ to be smooth?

My definition is:
A curve $r :\mathbb{R}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth iff it's $C^\infty$.

Is this a correct statement ?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes only $C^1$ is required. Or... some authors write the expression like *smooth enough*. What does it mean? If you want to compute, say, a curvature, you need $C^2$, so in th is context *smoooth enough* means $C^2$. And so on...